# Entity Framework DeleteObject query a lot of items

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a problem trying to delete an object with Entity Framework, I previously query the context to get a list of objects I need to delete, then one by one I call deleteobject

```
IQueryable result = context.CustomObjects.Where(t=>t.Property = something)

foreach (CustomObject customObj in result)
{
      context.DeleteObject(customObj);
}
```

When I call DeleteObject EF executes a weird query, something like that:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[Value1] AS [Value1], 
[Extent1].[Value2] AS [Value2], 
[Extent1].[Value3] AS [Value3], 
FROM [CustomObject] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=59
```

This query seems to search all the object with ID = something, but ID it is just part of the entity key that is indeed composed by 3 fields, so it attaches like n thousands items and make the process very slow, that is a behavior I can't understand, I always deleted object in this way and I have never had such a problem

can someone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could be fetching mutiple objects as defined by your where query. Also for each object you fetch, you will be fetching all fields on the object CustomObject.

The query thats being executed is a select query so this confirms the above behaviour.

If you want better performance then I recommend that you do something like this:

```
var entityToDelete = new SomeEntity();
SomeEntity.PK = 12;
var context = new YourContextntities();
context.YourEntitites.Attach(entityToDelete);
context.YourEntitites.Remove(entityToDelete);
context.SaveChanges();
```